# How to vs-mda-remote when remote cordova install requires sudo?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, cordova, npm

I'm attempting to use vs-mda-remote to build my Cordova app remotely on my Mac from Visual Studio.

Despite having already NPM installed Cordova on the Mac globally (using Sudo), the Visual Studio remote build keeps attempting to install it again on the Mac.  This fails because you cannot run vs-mda-remote using Sudo (it will immediately error and exit) and installation of Cordova requires root (at least with my Mac's configuration).

What am I doing wrong?

```
>  ------ Remote build log follows
1>  4.3.0
1>  Installing Cordova tools {0} for project from NPM. This could take a few minutes... cordova@4.3.0
1>
1>MDAVSCLI : npm WARN locking error : EACCES, open '/Users/halexanderw/.npm/_locks/cordova-b6c5e32b0cf25697.lock'
1>  npm WARN locking     at Error (native)
1>  npm WARN locking  /Users/halexanderw/.npm/_locks/cordova-b6c5e32b0cf25697.lock failed { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/halexanderw/.npm/_locks/cordova-b6c5e32b0cf25697.lock']
1>  npm WARN locking   errno: -13,
1>  npm WARN locking   code: 'EACCES',
1>  npm WARN locking   path: '/Users/halexanderw/.npm/_locks/cordova-b6c5e32b0cf25697.lock' }
1>  npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
1>  npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "cordova@4.3.0"
1>  npm ERR! node v0.12.5
1>  npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
1>
1>  npm ERR! Attempt to unlock /Users/halexanderw/remote-builds/node_modules/cordova/4.3.0/node_modules/cordova, which hasn't been locked
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `npm cache clear` resolved the problem.  I read somewhere that NPM can get stuck requiring sudo for every NPM install if your first install uses sudo.  I don't know if that is true or not, but that fits my symptoms.